# Java parsing XML with multiple arguments

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to parse an xml file with the structure given below and store the data to mysql DB. But, I'm not sure from where to start, since this is a xml structure I never faced before. 
Dozens of examples over the internet treats a structure where every attribute is bounded by its tag. 
For instance, this is excellent starting point, but xml structure is way different than mine. 
https://dzone.com/articles/load-xml-into-mysql-using-java

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Models>
    <Model id="1">
        <Nodes>
            <Node i="0" key="" name="Node 0" Vb_kV="225" gsh="0" bsh="0"/>
            <Node i="1" key="" name="Node 1" Vb_kV="380" gsh="0" bsh="0"/>
            <Node i="2" key="" name="Node 2" Vb_kV="225" gsh="0" bsh="0"/>
        </Nodes>
        <Loads>
            <Load node="0" key="" name="" P0="0.058" P1="0"/>
            <Load node="2" key="" name="" P0="1.425" P1="0"/>
            <Load node="4" key="" name="" P0="0.328" P1="0"/>
        </Loads>
        <Generators>
            <Generator pos="0" node="1246" key="" name="""/>
            <Generator pos="1" node="1333" key="" name="""/>
            <Generator pos="2" node="8700" key="" name=""/>         
        </Generators>
        <Branches>
            <Branch pos="0" nodeFrom="691" nodeTo="0" key="" name="" />
            <Branch pos="1" nodeFrom="260" nodeTo="1" key="" name="" />
            <Branch pos="2" nodeFrom="660" nodeTo="1" key="" name="" />
        </Branches>
        <Measurements>
            <Node>
            <Meas node="1" type="Z" val="0" w="1000"/>
                <Meas node="3" type="Z" val="0" w="1000"/>
                <Meas node="6" type="Z" val="0" w="1000"/>
                <Meas node="7" type="Z" val="0" w="1000"/>
            </Node>
            <Branch>
                <Meas branch="0" node="691"/>
                <Meas branch="0" node="691"/>
                <Meas branch="1" node="260"/>
            </Branch>
        </Measurements>
    </Model>
</Models>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the XML, or are you asking us to design your database schema for you?

Comment: No, DB design is not problem to me. I am not sure how to parse xml structure like this.

Comment: Dear Andreas, I am just asking for the reference or clue, not for solutions. I already have working example with different xml structure and couldn't find any with similar. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: So in what way is adjusting the code you do have to the new xml structure troubling you? I'll ask again: *Show us what you tried!* --- Your question is way *too broad* to be answered. We don't know the database you want to update, and we don't know what issue you have with navigating the DOM to get the information needed to update that database, so it's impossible for us to help.